# How to get newline character in TextField

Tags: flutter, newline, textfield, textinput

I am using Stream chat API for the chat application. And while sending message I want to use the newline character in the textinput but I tried, the following code. It isn't working.
And I am not finding any fixes, on the internet. Any help would be grateful appreciated.

```
                     child: TextField(
                          textInputAction: TextInputAction.newline,
                          keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
                          controller: controller,
                          onChanged: (val) {
                            StreamChannel.of(context).channel.keyStroke();
                          },
                          style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 14),
                          decoration: const InputDecoration(
                            hintText: 'Type something...',
                            border: InputBorder.none,
                          ),
                          onSubmitted: (_) => _sendMessage(),
                        ),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*In your TextField, add*

```
   maxLines: null,
```

**Or**

```
   maxLines: 5,
```

whatever you want.

Answer (score 1):

When you hit the return or enter key the on submit _sendMessage() is called. Please try removing on submit and new line should work also make sure that the maxline is set to null so its not restricted to add any number of lines

Comment: When i hit the return _sendMessage() was actually not called. It just didn't go to the next line.

Comment: Adding the maxline to null, solved my problem , thank you !